# How to enqueue Coroutines viewModelScope job after GlobalScope one

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an application scope function which requests access token from a server like so

```
fun getToken() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        ...
        val response = webservice.getToken().awaitResponse()
        //save token
    }
}
```

Also I have functions in repositories which request data from the server and which are launched from view models like so

```
//in a ViewModel
fun getData() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.getData()
    }
}

//in a Repository
fun getData() {
    ...
    val response = webservice.getData().awaitResponse()
    //handle response
}
```

How do I make it that data requests are sent only if there is access token available?

The only thing which comes to my mind is check for and request token if needed before each data request like this

```
fun getData() {
    var response: Response
    token?.let {
        response = webservice.getToken().awaitResponse()
        //save token
    }
    ...
    response = webservice.getData().awaitResponse()
    //handle response
}
```

but is this the right approach to use when there are many different data requests in  different repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
object InternalScope {
    private val tokenJob = GlobalScope.launch {
        response = webservice.getToken().awaitResponse()
    }

    suspend fun <T> runWithContext(
        context: CoroutineContext,
        block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
    ): T {
        tokenJob.join()
        return withContext(context, block)
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
InternalScope.runWithContext(Dispatchers.IO){}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to coroutines. Can you please expand a bit on how to use this?

Comment: @yaugenka Do you know how to use `withContext(){}` in coroutines?

Comment: I use it like: `launch { val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {} }`

Comment: ok now replace `withContext` with `InternalScope.runWithContext`. Thats it.